# Xcode 7 specific static framework warnings

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I have a static framework that is compiling perfectly on `Xcode 6`, but it's producing the following warning on `Xcode 7 (beta5)` for each of my framework's classes:

> while processing /Path-to-MyFramework/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework(MyFrameworkClass.o):
>   warning:
>
> /var/folders/_j/hqhnz9xd2qv_39dd1vdmw1nc0000gn/C/org.llvm.clang.MY-USERNAME/ModuleCache/2YCOBXU93NY4O/Foundation-K7W1BMS6PHG4.pcm:
>   No such file or directory

What is the source of these warnings and how do I eliminate them?

Comment: Ask that at Apple's developer forums.

Comment: You mean static libraries. Frameworks are not static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by setting 'Enable Modules' to NO in the project's Build Settings.

Comment: When you set enable modules to NO, if there are class forwarding in your code then it give compile error at that place.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of the default build setting change from Xcode6 to xcode7:

Xcode 6:
DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT = "dwarf-with-dsym";

Xcode 7:
DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT = "dwarf";

Change it accordingly and then warnings should go away

[image]